# How to use REST to separate model, view and control into two parts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails, I want to separate model, view and control into two parts and put them on two different servers. Can I achieve this by REST? How should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean two different RESTful resources exposed through Rails? (not sure from the wording)

Easiest way would just be to create two separate rails applications - one for each resource to be exposed, and deploy them to different servers. They could even both point at the same database if required, or they could have their own each.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, MVC web development is independent of the REST architectural style—MVC is usually used to implement the back-end serving of a resource's representation. It is possible, though, to model each of M, V, and C as resources:

Any **model** resource can accept a *GET* operation to query its state, a *PUT* operation for setting its state, *POST* for appending to it, and *DELETE* for removal. You still have the problem of representing the state without a **view** resource.

A **view** resource can return a representation of a given state (in some bare-bones representation or something, like with XML) via a *POST* operation, I guess, unless the view's data is small enough to use a *GET* operation.

A **controller** resource can accept a *GET* operation for queries and *POST* for form processing.

I don't think that this makes much sense to do, unless you're building some kind of loosley-coupled, heavily cached, distributed MVC engine.